# How to perfom spark data load and perform a transformation efficently

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have been trying to run an application using apache spark, in general it takes information from a series of database tables and creates a Dataset that contains columns with collections. This goes into a map() using a lambda. currently it takes 140,000 composite records from the database.

In order to make the data load dataset, we go through five dataset joins that contain the information of each table, most of them are lists that are related to the key of the first dataset

after that just a simple computation is done taking values and operating on them, there are no nested loops or unnecessary loops

The cluster that is being used has 9 workers with 8 cores each and 64 GB of memory. the spark configuration is the default and despite this the logs always present the same exceptions:

```
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 0
```

the configuration is the next

```
config.set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0");
config.set("spark.speculation", "true");
config.set("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "600");
config.set("spark.driver.memory","64g");
config.set("spark.executor.memory","64g");
```

Comment: Can you please add your code here

Answer (score 0):

Either add swap, or configure the worker/executor to use less memory in addition with using MEMORY_AND_DISK storage level for several persists.

The way to solve this is to do the following steps:

1. Increase the number of shuffle-partitions:

   --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=<some-high-number-lets say 200>
2. You can do after increasing the number of shuffle partitions is to decrease the storage part of the spark memory if you are not persisting or caching any dataframe. By default the storage part is 0.5 and execution part is also 0.5 . To reduce the storage part you can set in your spark-submit command the following configuration

   --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.3
3. Apart from the above two things you can also set executor overhead memory.

   --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2g

   This is off-heap memory that is used for Virtual Machine overheads, interned
   strings etc.
4. Apart from this , you can limit the number of files processed in a particular microbatch by setting the maxFilesPerTrigger to a smaller value say 10.